# If I reference an object property of an object that goes out of scope is the outer object eligible to be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

In the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public SmallObject SmallThing { get; set; }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        var largeThing = new LargeObject();
        SmallThing = largeThing.SmallThing;
    }

}
```

after `MyMethod()` has executed I have a reference to `SmallThing` but no reference to `largeThing`.  Is Dot Net able to recognize that `largeThing` is eligible to be collected while the `SmallObject` instance it contained is not so eligible?  Or does Dot Net somehow remember the original association between `largeThing` and `SmallThing`?  (You may assume that `SmallThing` *does not* contain an explicit backward reference to `largeThing` created by the programmer).

Comment: Yes `largeThing` will be eligible for collection.

Comment: So does this mean that `MyClass.SmallThing` may get overwritten after `largeThing` is disposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `largeThing` will be collectable as soon as you pass the line

```
SmallThing = largeThing.SmallThing;
```

it does not need to even wait for `MyMethod` to return for it to be able to collect it (This assumes running release mode without the debugger attached). As soon as the last useage of `largeThing` is passed it will be eligible for collection.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no active references to `largeThing` it will be eligible for garbage collection.  There are no "hidden" or implicit references back from `SmallThing` that would keep it from being eligible.